# Why is ExtendedTimeZone not recognized when using .NET Micro Framework 4.0?

Tags: .net, .net-micro-framework

First example in the book (Expert .NET Micro Framework - 2nd Edition) uses Microsoft.SPOT.ExtendedTimeZone to set the time zone, but I get a "Cannot resolve symbol 'ExtendedTimeZone'" error in Visual Studio 2008.

I've installed the .NET Micro Framework 4.0 SDK.
I referenced Microsoft.SPOT.Native.dll and Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.
I'm "using" Microsoft.SPOT and Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.

What am I missing here?

PS: Microsoft MSDN tells me the class is available in NETMF 4.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee433569.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/475-still-learning-internet-way-to-grab-date-and-time-on-startup/page__p__3533__hl__timezone__fromsearch__1#entry3533)

The NETMF documentation is in error as
Microsoft.SPOT.ExtendedTimeZone.SetTimeZone() was dropped after version 3.0
in favor of an intrinsic time service in framework. I.E. SNTP is built into
the framework.